# Azure machine learning templates in ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ai

Do ARM templates offer the built-in functionality to create Azure Machine Learning Pipelines?

[The documentation that I have found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/?view=azure-ml-py) describes using the SDK to create Azure ML Pipelines.

My searches in [the ARM template documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/) have not resulted in anything about machine learning pipelines.

I am asking because someone else here might know a better answer than what my research is showing.

Answer (score 0):

> Do ARM templates offer the built-in functionality to create Azure Machine Learning Pipelines?

According to this [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-ml-pipelines?view=azureml-api-2#getting-started-best-practices),

As of Now, ARM templates do not have built-in features for creating Azure Machine Learning pipelines. To create pipelines in Azure Machine Learning, they recommend using:

1. CLI
2. Python SDK v2
3. UI

However, you can use the Azure Machine Learning SDK to create pipelines. The Azure Machine Learning service provides a managed API to register and manage models, and you can use Azure ML Compute to create and manage clusters to execute pipelines.

**Reference:**

[Create and run machine learning pipelines using components with the Azure Machine Learning SDK v2 - Azure Machine Learning | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-component-pipeline-python?view=azureml-api-2)